# Why can't I can't echo objQuery in this code?

Tags: php

I can't echo in the last line. I have already checked the spelling of the database and variable names; they are correct. I have no idea why it doesn't work, please help.

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("projectwebp");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM check_report WHERE Check_DateTime = '$datebus'";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
echo $objQuery["Bus_Rearnumber"];


while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $num++;
    if($objResult["Bus_Rearnumber"] == "1"){
        $rearnumber = "/";
        ?>

From the previous page <a href="reportbus.php?datebus=<?php echo $busdatereport_newformat ?>">Page2</a>
```

and I've checked the value already; it's completely fine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, i forgot add this statement for u guys.
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{ $num++;
  if($objResult["Bus_Rearnumber"] == "1"){
    $rearnumber = "/";
..
..
}

Comment: Put actual code in your question and for where you assign `$datebus`.

Comment: From the previous page
<a href="reportbus.php?datebus=<?php echo $busdatereport_newformat ?>">Page2</a>

and i check the value already it's completely fine ('2014-12-17')

Comment: @kongza557 There is a "edit" button under your question! you can use it! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27514580/edit

Comment: Where is `$datebus` coming from? Plus why are you doing `Error Query [".$strSQL."]`? You need to check for real error `or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: your code doesn't make sense... you are putting stuff outside php tags. Please clean so we can help you.

Comment: @Manatax actually i pull all in the php tag but i just post only some code here.

Comment: If you're talking about `echo $objQuery["Bus_Rearnumber"];`, Fred -ii- is right. You need to fetch before accessing row values.

Comment: Also, take into account that that method has been deprecated. It is suggested that you use MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php